# How to get name & link of parent page in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to have a link on children pages that is not only the name of the parent page, but also links to the parent page in DNN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this in your skin ascx file

```
<a href="<%= ((DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo)PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs[ PortalSettings.ActiveTab.Level - 1 ]).FullUrl %>">
<%= ((DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo)PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs[ PortalSettings.ActiveTab.Level - 1 ]).TabName %>
</a>
```

Note: this is for a C# skin.

Comment: The amount of times I come back to this post makes me wish I could upvote it more than once!