# In DNN 9 - How do I display the name and link of the Active Page's Root level Parent?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to add some code I found on this forum in my skin .ascx file to display the name and link of the Active Page's Root level Parent. I am using DNN 9.1.1.
Here is where I found the code:
[How to get name & link of parent page in DNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261564/how-to-get-name-link-of-parent-page-in-dnn)

```
<a href="<%= ((DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo)PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs[0]).FullUrl %>"><%= ((DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo)PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs[0]).TabName %></a>
```

It works visually, but I am getting some weird issues. With the code added, while in the edit mode, it makes a class="DNNAjaxPanel" div disappear. This div is used to help when you drag a module into a Content Panel. It is the div just above this div class="DNNEmptyPane dnnSortable dnnModuleManager ui-sortable"

Use the Inspect Element feature of your browser and you will see what I mean.

Here is a Screen shot with the div class="DnnAjaxPanel" that is there before I use the code:
[Screen shot with div class="DnnAjaxPanel"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DtRe.png)

When I add the code it makes that div disappear. Then when I add a module to that Content Pane it makes all the modules go to that one Pane no matter what other content pane they are currently in.

Is this a bug with DNN 9.1.1 or can I not use the code in my skin ascx file?

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0):

You Are probably using a VB skin. You can check this at the top of the page with "language": `<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"`

The below code works with DNN 9, tested it.

```
<a href="<%= CType(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs(0),DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo).FullUrl %>">
    <%= CType(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs(0),DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo).TabName %>
</a>
```

C# version

```
<a href="<%= ((DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo)PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs[0]).FullUrl %>">
    <%= ((DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo)PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs[0]).TabName %>
</a>
```

Comment: I am using C#. This is what I have at the top of the skin ascx page.

<%@ Control language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin" %>

The code for your C# Version is the same as what I am using.

When you tested in DNN 9.1.1 did it makes the div class="DNNAjaxPanel" disappear? Please see my screen shot link above.

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: PLEASE TEST by adding the code to a C# skin ascx file. Then login to DNN admin and try to add a few modules in different content panes and see what happens.

Then, use the Inspect Element feature of your browser and you will see that the div class="DNNAjaxPanel" has disappeared. If you Inspect Element of a Skin ascx page that doesn't have the code and you will see the div class="DNNAjaxPanel" is there.

Note: the div class="DNNAjaxPanel" is the div just above the div class="DNNEmptyPane dnnSortable dnnModuleManager ui-sortable"

Is this a issue or bug with DNN 9.1.1?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: I've checked again with the Xcillion skin changed to C#. I could not find a problem, everything still worked after adding the code to the page. However I am using `9.0.1`.

Comment: It must be a bug in DNN 9.1.1 because if I add this code <%=PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName%> into my C# skin ascx page and then go into DNN admin edit mode it makes the div class="DNNAjaxPanel" disappear. Is there a place on the DNN Community Website that I can report a possible bug?

Comment: The bug happens if this code <%=PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName%> or similar code is on your C# skin ascx page. Then you add an existing module (do not make a copy) and then try to add several existing modules to different content panes.

Please do test! I am using DNN 9.1.1