# How do I get current DNN page name for javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke

I am trying to assign the current DNN page name to a variable in javascript, but I cannot find the correct coding. 
I searched the web but I only found this usage, but is doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var tabName = <% =TabName %>; </script>
```

I am using document.title for now, but I really want to use PageName.

Here is my javascript that is currently working:

```
/* add active class to Mega-Menu item if Page Title matches data-linkname */ var tabName = document.title; $('.megamenu .second-level-list li[data-pagename="' + tabName + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Here is what I really want to use:

```
/* add active class to Mega-Menu item if Page Name matches data-linkname */ var tabName = '<% =TabName %>'; $('.megamenu .second-level-list li[data-pagename="' + tabName + '"]').addClass('active');
```

I also tried this but it didn't work.

```
var tabName = '<% =TabController.CurrentPage.TabName %>';
```

What would be the correct way to assign the current page name to a variable in javascript?

I am using DNN PLATFORM v.09.01.01 and 4.6.NET FRAMEWORK

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code in my [HammerHead](https://github.com/ChrisHammond/HammerHead/blob/master/Home.ascx) skin to output the tab name out to the page for display, no reason you can't use this same code inside a script tag to create a javascript variable.

```
<%=PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName%>
```

Comment: If I use it in a separate javascript file that is in a DnnJsInclude it does not work. <dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="DnnJsColsFunctions" runat="server" FilePath="assets/js/functions.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" ForceProvider="DnnFormBottomProvider" />. If I have the javascript directly in the skin ascx file it does work. Is there a way to make it work from inside a js file that is being included and not in the actual skin ascx file? Thanks

Comment: Also, I noticed if I add that code to my C# skin ascx page I get some issues while in the DNN admin edit mode. See my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48666562/in-dnn-9-how-do-i-display-the-name-and-link-of-the-active-pages-root-level-pa
 I think there are some bugs in DNN 9.1.1 when you add code like <%=PortalSettings.ActiveTab.TabName%> right into your skin ascx file. Can you please read that post link above and test. Thanks